# how to have an emulator of same UI as of physical device

Tags: android, android-studio, genymotion, android-virtual-device

**Use case**

I want my emulator UI as exact replica of Actual phone device(Samsung galaxy S7).

Target phone : **Samsung galaxy S7**

**What i tried :**

I uesd Genymotion and AVD both to create an exact replica of Samsung galaxy S7 , but the **UI** differs.

**Genymotion UI of samsung galaxy S7**

[image: Genymotion_UI of Samsung galaxy S7]

**Actual\Expected UI of phone**

[image: Actual\Expected UI of phone]

Can anyone please suggest how can i get the exact replica of UI in AVD or in Genymotion

Note: I already have tried with samsung UI skin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, that is not possible: vendors like Samsung do not provide the source code for their custom user interface, so they cannot be integrated in Genymotion ROMs.